# General question on notations when dealing multiplicative and additive modulo

Tags: group-theory, elementary-number-theory

One of the property for the requirement for a set to be a group is associativity.

Under ordinary multiplication:

$\large{a(bc)=(ab)c}$

Under ordinary addition:

$\large{a+(b+c)=(a+b)+c}$

What about under multiplicative modulo and additive modulo?

Do we write it, respectively as:

$\large{a(bc) \pmod n =(ab)c \pmod n}$

and

$\large{a+(b+c) \pmod n=(a+b)+c\pmod n}$

Comment: Why do you tag your questions with set theory tags? This is not the first time it happens, and this is rarely the right tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to be precise, you must specify what your $a,b,c$ are.
$\def\nn{\mathbb{N}}$
$\def\zz{\mathbb{Z}}$

Given $n \in \nn^+$ and $a,b,c \in \zz/n\zz$, we have the exact equality $(a+b)+c = a+(b+c)$ and $(ab)c = a(bc)$.

Given $n \in \nn^+$ and $a,b,c \in \zz$, we have an equivalence relation which we can denote by "$\equiv_{\pmod{n}}$" which lets us write "$(a+b)+c \equiv_{\pmod{n}} a+(b+c)$" and "$(ab)c \equiv_{\pmod{n}} a(bc)$". Often people choose to write "$(a+b)+c \equiv a+(b+c) \pmod{n}$" and "$(ab)c \equiv a(bc) \pmod{n}$" instead.

Comment: People, please stop editing my answers unless it's an obvious mistake and you know what you are doing. If it is not made clear that it is really an equivalence relation, it is not good!